# Bootstrap alert and confirm dialog box + Make with modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make Bootstrap modal and confirm dialog box with bootstrap alert.

So can you please any one give me steps how to implement ?

Do I need to add any js file ?

I do not want to make same as header message as simple given by bootstrap i want make with modal...

Please let me know if any one know..

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: sorry, it is link is not answer related of my qyestion

Comment: nobody's going to just do your work for you here. Show what you've tried and people might be kind enough to point to your mistakes

Comment: Ok I want to know any one need to make which have make alert with modal popup, I have just made custom alert in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize some class of bootstrap for modal + alert

```
"<div id=\"myModal\" class=\"modal hide fade custom-modal\" tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"dialog\" aria-labelledby=\"myModalLabel\" aria-hidden=\"true\">"+
                                                       "<div class=\"alert alert-danger fade in custom-alert\">"+
                                                    "<strong>Please select atleast one favourite user.</strong>"+
                                                    "</div><div class=\"modal-footer custom-modal-footer\">"+
                                                    "<button class=\"Custom-alert-close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-hidden=\"true\">Ok</button></div></div>";
```

//css

```
.custom-modal{padding:0%!important; margin-bottom :0% !important; top:30%!important}
.custom-alert{margin-bottom :0% !important;padding:6% !important;text-align:center;}
.custom-modal-footer{background-color:#F2DEDE !important;border-radius:0 0 6px 6px !important;padding:7px 15px 15px !important;text-align:center!important; border-top:0px!important;}
.Custom-alert-close{background-color:#B94A48;border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px;padding:4px 12px; border:0px;color:#FFF;}
```